# session['username'] not working with sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, flask, session

I'm going crazy. This is the test.py file I made that worked manually:

```
name = "Club"
description = "Description"
goals = "Goals"
user_id = "aa"

c = db.cursor()
c.execute("INSERT INTO clubs (user_id, name, description, goals) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (user_id, name, description, goals))
db.commit()
```

What I want is to replace user_id with session['username'], which has already been assigned in a different function. I know this has been assigned because this renders "Hello aa!"

```
@app.route("/profile")
def profile():
    return render_template("profile.html", username=session['username'])
```

--
This is the code that does not work (aka returns club.html):

```
@app.route("/club", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def club():
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form.get("name")
        description = request.form.get("description")
        goals = request.form.get("goals")

        c = c = db.cursor()

        c.execute("INSERT INTO clubs (user_id, name, description, goals) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (session['username'], name, description, goals))
        db.commit()

        # Redirect user to home page
        return render_template("index.html")

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("club.html")
```

Comment: and what has this to do with sql, have you checked request method?

Comment: the sql table "clubs" does not update with the new form fields.

Comment: of course when you say that club.html open so the method can't be post, so have you debugged it an check what it contains?

Comment: you're awesome and totally right. I was looking in the wrong place. Forgot to write method="post" in the form html. Thank nbk!